# JavaScript variable in the body of a fetch request

Tags: javascript, post, fetch

I want to send a request to an API and the info has to be in the body and I want to use one variable in that. But when I use `(size)` or `{size}` or `$ {size}` it doesn't work. How to load a variable there:

```
"body": "[\"variables\":{\"addToCartInput\":{\"productId\":\ ** SIZE ** \,\"clientMutationId\":\"addToCartMutation\"}}]",
```

```
var SIZE = "NI115N001-A130045000";
fetch("https://www.zalando.pl/api/graphql/add-to-cart/", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-language": "pl-PL,pl;q=0.9",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "x-zalando-feature": "pdp",
  },
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": "[\"variables\":{\"addToCartInput\":{\"productId\":\ ** SIZE ** \,\"clientMutationId\":\"addToCartMutation\"}}]",
  "method": "POST"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why bother with quotes escaping, concatenation or interpolation ([Template litterals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)) when there is a method to [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) an array and/or object?

```
var SIZE = "NI115N001-A130045000";

// Prepare the data
var data_to_send = [
  variables:{
    addToCartInput:{
      productId: SIZE,  // The variable is used here
      clientMutationId: "addToCartMutation" // Assuming that is a string
    }
  }
];

// Stringify the data
var data_stringified = JSON.stringify(data_to_send);

fetch("https://www.zalando.pl/api/graphql/add-to-cart/", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-language": "pl-PL,pl;q=0.9",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "x-zalando-feature": "pdp",
  },
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": data_stringified, // Use the stringified data here
  "method": "POST"
});
```

[Fetch Documentation where there is a similar example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options)

Answer (score 0):

These are two ways to do that

1.

```
"[\"variables\":{\"addToCartInput\":{\"productId\": " + SIZE + " ,\"clientMutationId\":\"addToCartMutation\"}}]"
```

2. 

```
`["variables":{"addToCartInput":{"productId": ${SIZE},"clientMutationId":"addToCartMutation"}}]`
```

Please note that first one is using double quotes. While second one is using template literals.